# Find the measurement of the largest angle

Tags: trigonometry

ABC is a triangle in which: 
P - a = 8 cm , P - b = 6 cm , P - c = 4 cm .

Find measurement of the largest angle in triangle where 2P = a + b+ c

Edit : 
My answer:

$$2P = a + b + c$$

$$P = \frac{a + b + c}{2}$$

$$P - b = \frac{a + b +c}{2} - b = 6$$

$$ = \frac{a + b +c}{2} - \frac{2b}{2} = 6$$

$$ = \frac{a - b +c}{2}  = 6$$

$$ = {a - b +c}  = 12$$

---

$$P - a = \frac{a + b +c}{2} - a = 8$$

$$ = \frac{a + b +c}{2} - \frac{2a}{2} = 8$$

$$ = \frac{-a + b +c}{2}  = 8$$

$$ = {-a + b +c}  = 16$$

---

$${-a + b +c}  = 16$$

$${a - b +c}  = 12$$

$$2c = 28$$

$$c = 14$$

---

$$P - c = 4$$
$$P - 14 = 4$$
$$P = 18$$

---

$$P - a = 8$$
$$18 - a = 8$$
$$a = 10$$

---

$$P - b = 6$$
$$18 - b = 6$$
$$b = 12$$

---

$$a < b < c$$
Then angle C is largest angle

$$ Cos C = \frac{10^2+12^2−14^2}{2 •10 • 12}=\frac{1}{5}$$

Then angle $$<C = arccos \frac{1}{5} = 78.46$$

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-cosine-law.html

Comment: I know cosine rule ... problem is how to get the length of sides

Comment: What is $\text{P}$?

Comment: 2P = a + b + c.

Comment: Are the sides of the triangle $a,b,c$?

Comment: Yes a,b and c are sides of triangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$c=(P-a)+(P-b) = 8+6 =14$$
The same procedure we get $a=10$ and $b= 12$. So

$$\cos \gamma = {10^2+12^2-14^2\over 2\cdot 10\cdot 12} ={1\over 5}$$
Thus $\gamma =\arccos{1\over 5}=...$

Answer (score 0):

Well, we know for every triangle:

$$
\begin{cases}
\angle\alpha^\circ+\angle\beta^\circ+\angle\gamma^\circ=180^\circ\\
\\
\frac{\left|\text{A}\right|}{\sin\angle\alpha}=\frac{\left|\text{B}\right|}{\sin\angle\beta}=\frac{\left|\text{C}\right|}{\sin\angle\gamma}\\
\\
\left|\text{A}\right|^2=\left|\text{B}\right|^2+\left|\text{C}\right|^2-2\left|\text{B}\right|\left|\text{C}\right|\cos\angle\alpha\\
\\
\left|\text{B}\right|^2=\left|\text{A}\right|^2+\left|\text{C}\right|^2-2\left|\text{A}\right|\left|\text{C}\right|\cos\angle\beta\\
\\
\left|\text{C}\right|^2=\left|\text{A}\right|^2+\left|\text{B}\right|^2-2\left|\text{A}\right|\left|\text{B}\right|\cos\angle\gamma
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Now, we know that $\left|\text{A}\right|=\text{P}-8$, $\left|\text{B}\right|=\text{P}-6$ and $\left|\text{C}\right|=\text{P}-4$:

$$
\begin{cases}
\angle\alpha^\circ+\angle\beta^\circ+\angle\gamma^\circ=180^\circ\\
\\
\frac{\text{P}-8}{\sin\angle\alpha}=\frac{\text{P}-6}{\sin\angle\beta}=\frac{\text{P}-4}{\sin\angle\gamma}\\
\\
\left(\text{P}-8\right)^2=\left(\text{P}-6\right)^2+\left(\text{P}-4\right)^2-2\cdot\left(\text{P}-6\right)\cdot\left(\text{P}-4\right)\cdot\cos\angle\alpha\\
\\
\left(\text{P}-6\right)^2=\left(\text{P}-8\right)^2+\left(\text{P}-4\right)^2-2\cdot\left(\text{P}-8\right)\cdot\left(\text{P}-4\right)\cdot\cos\angle\beta\\
\\
\left(\text{P}-4\right)^2=\left(\text{P}-8\right)^2+\left(\text{P}-6\right)^2-2\cdot\left(\text{P}-8\right)\cdot\left(\text{P}-6\right)\cdot\cos\angle\gamma
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Which also gives:

$$
\begin{cases}
\angle\alpha^\circ+\angle\beta^\circ+\angle\gamma^\circ=180^\circ\\
\\
\frac{\text{P}-8}{\sin\angle\alpha}=\frac{\text{P}-6}{\sin\angle\beta}=\frac{\text{P}-4}{\sin\angle\gamma}\\
\\
\frac{\text{P}+2}{\text{P}-4}=2\cdot\cos\angle\alpha\\
\\
1+\frac{3}{\text{P}-8}+\frac{3}{4-\text{P}}=2\cdot\cos\angle\beta\\
\\
1+\frac{6}{8-\text{P}}=2\cdot\cos\angle\gamma
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

So, we can write (for example):

$$1+\frac{1}{2}-\cos\angle\gamma+\frac{3}{4-\text{P}}=2\cdot\cos\angle\beta\tag4$$

Answer (score 0):

$(p-4)^2=(p-8)^2+(p-6)^2-2 (p-6) (p-8) \cos \widehat{C}$

$$ \cos \widehat{C}=\frac{p-14}{2 (p-8)}\to \widehat{C}=\arccos \frac{p-14}{2 (p-8)}$$

Hope this helps
$$...$$
[image]